# Como posso verificar se é um robô do facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

Existe alguma forma de, com PHP, verificar se o acesso ao servidor está sendo feito por um robô/bot do facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8626828/3473971) do SO gringo:

```
if (
    strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "facebookexternalhit/") !== false ||          
    strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Facebot") !== false
) {
    // é provavelmente um bot do facebook
}
else {
    // nao eh um bot Facebook
}
```

A lista completa esta [aqui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler) mas esses dois sao os mais usados.